# How can I correctly format my Web Service to return data from SQL to jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I've been all over Google, attempting one example after another for both AJAX and jQuery AutoComplete.

I've decided on using **jQuery**'s script to render the **autocomplete** method on my page and I'm using a web service to collect data from my SQL Ce data base.

Here is the **error message** I receive from jquery and I'm pretty sure that it derives from my webs service... **Marr is short for Marriott, the search term I begin to type..**

**{"Message":"@SearchText : Marr - Input string was not in a correct format.","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.FillParameterDataBindings(Boolean verifyValue)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n   at GetClients.GetClientNames(String prefix) in c:\Users\CRH-DEV\Desktop\Dev Projects\HelpDesk\App_Code\GetClients.cs:line 42","ExceptionType":"System.FormatException"}**

The error derives from **line 42 of my webservice**'s .cs but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking at. I'm guessing the data is not correctly formatted.

The example I am using derives from this website...

[Implement jQuery Autocomplete using Web Service in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-jQuery-Autocomplete-using-Web-Service-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

Here is my complete webservice...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Service_CS
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
 // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class GetClients : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

public GetClients()
{

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string[] GetClientNames(string prefix)
{
    List<string> customers = new List<string>();
    using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Name], [ID] FROM [Current] WHERE " +
            "[Name] LIKE @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCeDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["Name"], sdr["ID"]));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return customers.ToArray();
    }
}
```

}

**My aspx Page..(head)**

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"
 type = "text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
 type = "text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jqueryui.css" rel = "Stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=ClientSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/GetClients.asmx/GetClientNames") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=hfClientID.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });

  });
</script>
```

**aspx (body)**..

```
    <h1>jQuery Autocomplete Lab</h1>
<asp:TextBox ID="ClientSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfClientID" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick = "Submit" />
```

If needing, I can post additional code but I think the issue is with my webservice.

I would highly appreciate any feedback on this issue. I think the webservices have been whats killing my on all of the examples I've tried.

Kind Regards,
-Cody

Comment: Which one is line 42? (It's the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` one, isn't it?)

Comment: My apologies, yes it is.

Comment: I think the problem may be lying in the line 39 `[Name] LIKE @SearchText + '%'`.

Comment: You should try like this `prefix = "'" + prefix + "%'";`.

Comment: It could be.
I've tried various examples that encapsulate similar parameters within the query.

Comment: And then change line 39 to `"[Name] LIKE @SearchText"`

Comment: @Devraj Gadhavi
That seems to resolve the error issue in my webservice.
Looking in the developer toolbar in FireFox, it looks like the service is now posting. 
I'm not sure it my aspx page is getting the data though. No errors but it's not doing anything at this point...I'll edit my original post and include the aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return JSON from you Webservice

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(YourArray);
```

also change the return type of you webservice function to string

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetClientNames(string prefix)
{
 //YOUR CODE
}
```

Comment: Adding JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); seems to help. I now get a message within the suggestion area. System.Collection.Generic.List
How would I format string json = js.Serialize(YourArray); with my array?